# Configuration Step in creating new Azure Pipeline is blank

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I have just setup Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-premises) and create a project then up source code to Azure Repos.

But when I create new build pipeline from Web Interface, after select source, I cannot select to create pipeline setting on `"Configure your pipeline"` Page because it was blank.

Is there any solution for this situation?

P.s: my source code run on .Net framework

Comment: Do you have any screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, seems you were stuck with below step:

[image]

There should be options as above, you just need to select one of it. Then system will auto create an `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

If it's totally blank, suggest you give a try with another browser first such as Chrome/Firefox/Edge, better with private mode enabled.

Besides, instead of creating YAML build pipeline. You could also give a try if you are able to create classic editor.

[image]

In this way, you should be able to create build pipeline through UI.

Comment: Thank for reply, in my case, it's totally blank, I will try "Use the classic editor".

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but a customer of mine recently had the same problem: A blank page at the "Configure your pipeline" step when trying to create a new YAML pipeline.

The workaround to fix it was rather surprising: We changed the language of the DevOps UI from German to English(US), and finally the page was no longer blank and the default templates were shown.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.